# XML Deserialize special characters

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to deserialize an xml-file which has an special character in one of its fields. The character is hex `0x05` and results in the xml-file to `&#x5;`.
I am able to serialize the object but its not possible to deserialize it again.
I am using this technique really often but this is the first time it doesnt work.
This is an minimal example of the problem:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace XMLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpecialCharacter testobject = new SpecialCharacter();
            string filename = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\testfile.xml";

            //serialize
            StreamWriter writer = System.IO.File.CreateText(filename);
            XmlSerializer xmlserialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SpecialCharacter));
            xmlserialize.Serialize(writer, testobject);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            //deserialize
            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);
            XmlSerializer xmldeserialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SpecialCharacter));
            testobject = (SpecialCharacter)xmldeserialize.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    public class SpecialCharacter
    {
        public string special = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x05).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a special reader that has its Normalization property set to false.

So instead of

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);
```

use

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
```

Now it should work.

Comment: It seems that microsoft suggests the use of `XmlReader` instead of `XmlTextReader`. Both work. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple(-ish) solutions here:

- Use an `XmlTextReader.Create` instead of `File.CreateText` and add `new XmlReaderSettings() { CheckCharacters = false }` as the second parameter. You should probably avoid doing that to be honest though, unless you're just working on files you've created yourself and know their contents.
- Serialize your `String` in Base64:

---

```
public class SpecialCharacter
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "special")]
    public String Base64
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(special));
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                special = null;
                return;
            }

            special = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value));
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public String special = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x05).ToString();
}
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem of reading the xml-file. the writing process doesnt change (the xml-file is the same). Also its not clear what you mean, because for writing I had to use an `XmlTextWriter` not an `XmlTextReader` or did I missunderstand something. The Base64-String is an good Idea but I always have a lot of files with this issue and its more important for me to be able to read them properly instead of changing my code for future-files. I like the `XmlIgnore` Attribute :)